# Changing JSON value in file from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

I have a JSON file with multiple objects(I am new to this, my terming may be off), and I want to be able to pull the data from the file, change a value, and save it to the file.

Example JSON file:

```
{ "food-price": "22" },
{ "water-price": "12"),
```

What I want to do is to change food-price to 30, and save it to the file, without changing anything else.

Comment: is your json file is array of object?

Answer (score 0):

In case what you looking for is inside of array, you should search it first.
After select the target, you can manipulate the value. After to do so, save the json
file using `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
const yourFile = require('./your-file.json')
const fs = require('fs')

//If your json is not iterable and holding just single object
(() =>{
   yourFile['food-price'] = 30
   fs.writeFileSync(
      '.your-file.json', 
      JSON.stringify(yourFile)
   )
})()

//If your json is iterable and holding multiple object
(() =>{
   for(const key in yourFile){
      if(key == "what you're looking for"){
         const obj = yourFile[key]
         obj['food-price'] = 30
         yourFile[key] = obj
      }
   }

   fs.writeFileSync(
      '.your-file.json', 
      JSON.stringify(yourFile)
   )
})()
```